# Android Studio Emulator terminates if notebook is connected to HP docking station

Tags: android-emulator

I am having an issue where the AVD emulator terminates if my HP notebook is connected to a HP docking station. My Android Studio version is 2022.1.1 Patch 2 and I am running it on a HP 17-cp0157ng notebook with Windows 11 Home installed. The docking station I am using the HP USB-C/A Universal Dock G2, L61608-001. My Android projects are stored on C:, with free space of 90 GB.

Running the emulator without the docking station works fine. However, if I connect the docking station first and then start the emulator, it terminates. I have tried using AVDs 'Galaxy Nexus API 33' and 'Pixel 2 API 30', but both have the same effect. I have also studied several postings and tried editing .ini-files, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio, but with no success. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.